# What other villages were affected by the events leading up to Hoard of the Dragon Queen?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, map-making

Running *Hoard of the Dragon Queen*, “Episode 3: The Dragon Hatchery” on Roll20 and I'm editing the map of the Sword Coast to show only the Greenfields and the route they marked.

I also want to put Xs on villages that

> the Cult attacked, but the book does not name any of the other targets.

Does anybody know or could recommend where to mark the map to show these villages?

Answer (score 5):

I would make some up if it were me.  Seriously, there aren't that many villages on the maps because they are too small to be significant (they might be 3 or 4 families than live near an inn on a trade route (like the Long Road or the North Road).  In fact, when I had my party play HotDQ, the first couple of villages that they encountered on the way to Waterdeep showed signs of having been raided by cultists (and I RPed the cultists appropriately to give hints).